# mouseover event on display:none (hidden) element (chrome & opera)

Tags: javascript, html, css, hidden, onmouseover

In brief:
display:none element gets mouseover event when i click a select menu that overlaps display:none element.

code summary:
A ul above a select element. ul has all but top li as display:none. Via JS, lower li's become display:block when you mouseover the displayed ul. On mouseout, lower li's become hidden again. (Its a hover and expand feature you may know for navigation.)

Expected behavior: Show top li only. Hover it and show all li's (full ul shown). Mouseout of ul and hide all but top li. (You can mouse around whole ul once its shown and you dont get mouseout event.

Problem:
I have a select dropdown right below the ul. Clicking select makes ul display. (Your cursor is now hovering the expanded ul.) This happens in chrome 36.0.1985.125 and Opera 21.0.1432.67. Does NOT happen in firefox 29.0.1. Here is the code as simple as i can make it. Click the last select option and see.

Question: What's the bug/unexpected behavior. Can i prevent this?

```
<style type="text/css">
ul{
    font-size:150%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}
select{
    display:inline;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show(name1,name2,name3,name4){
    document.getElementById(name1).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById(name2).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById(name3).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById(name4).style.display="block";
}
function hide(name1,name2,name3,name4){
    document.getElementById(name1).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(name2).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(name3).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(name4).style.display="none";
}
</script>

<ul onmouseover="show('id1','id2','id3','id4')" onmouseout="hide('id1','id2','id3','id4')">
    <li>asdf1</li>
    <li style="display:none" id="id1">asdf2</li>
    <li style="display:none" id="id2">asdf3</li>
    <li style="display:none" id="id3">asdf4</li>
    <li style="display:none" id="id4">asdf5</li>
</ul>
<br>
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: just shortened ul to 3 li. 2 hidden. now bug only happens when i click select where a 5th li would be, and it only expands for a sec. if i have 5 li the expand stays because my mouse is over it.

Comment: More info: styles unneeded. there is an exact area below my ul that when clicked on (and while clicking a select) the ul gets mouseover. adding or removing li's/options from ul or select list doesnt move that area. moving select lower with br doesnt move that area. the area can be outside the full expanded ul, in which case it expands for an instant then gets mouseout (retracts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with Chromium: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389163.  Unfortunately, there is no easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

try to bind onmouseover event in `<li>`

```
<ul onmouseout="hide('id1','id2','id3','id4')">
    <li onmouseover="show('id1','id2','id3','id4')">asdf1</li>
    <li style="display:none" id="id1">asdf2</li>
    <li style="display:none" id="id2">asdf3</li>
    <li style="display:none" id="id3">asdf4</li>
    <li style="display:none" id="id4">asdf5</li>
</ul>
```

I tested your code but not found the effect you described.
firstly,ul is block element and elements of display:none are disappeared in the window,clicking select won't enter ul's boundary unless you made wrong layout.
If this condition will happen in your choosing select's `<option>`,you should prevent select's `<option>` get across `<ul>`.

Comment: i want ul, when expanded, to run over other stuff. it saves space for a complex navigation. just noticed bug only happens on 5th li. if i remove that li, it happen in same area but ul only expands for a sec and goes back. still looking...

Comment: need mouseover on whole ul list. expected behavior: "mouse around whole ul once its shown" [well hey that should work, but doesnt for me]

Comment: pasting my exact code in 1 file. viewing with chrome, click select wher the fifth li would be. it expands the ul. BBL.

Comment: You did?I tried just as what I said in my answer but won't expand ul.Chrome,Firefox,Safari,Opera,even IE,It works well ,so I want you give a real example.